# How to fix "java: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, comparator

I'm using JB IntelliJ IDEA and trying to create a program which sorts Rectangles. But I can't fix

```
"Error:(28, 22) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method Rectangle(java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double)
  location: class io.github.vadimsam.rectsort.Rectangle".
```

What should I do?

NB: recreation of project didn't help me.

Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SComparator implements Comparator<Rectangle> {

    public int compare(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {
        return r1.area().compareTo(r2.area());

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       ArrayList<Rectangle> rectsArea = new ArrayList<>();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       SComparator comparator = new SComparator();

       while(true){
            System.out.print("A = ");
            Double a = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("B = ");
            Double b = input.nextDouble();
            Rectangle.Rectangle(a,b);
            rectsArea.sort(comparator);
            if (a  == 0) {
                System.out.println("Sorted ArrayList:");
                System.out.println(rectsArea);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle {
    public Double c, d;

    public Rectangle(Double c, Double d) {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    Double area() {
        return c * d;
    }
}
```

It should return sorted ArrayList

Comment: You should use the `new` keyword to create an instance of `Rectangle`. You are trying to execute the constructor as if it was a static method.

Comment: What do you expect `Rectangle.Rectangle(a,b);` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
Rectangle.Rectangle(a,b);
```

which is calling a static method named `Rectangle`, which is potentially part of `Rectangle` class, try to create an object using constructor that you declared in your `Rectangle` class to instantiate new rectangle object :

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(a, b);
```

You have not declared any static method named `Rectangle` in your `Rectangle` class, that is why this error appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the line

```
Rectangle.Rectangle(a,b);
```

This is incorrect syntax for instantiating your object since there's no method `Rectangle` in your rectangle class, only a constructor. The correct way to use the constructor is the following:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
  Rectangle.Rectangle(a,b);
```

means a call to a static method called `Rectangle` defined by the class `Rectangle`.  There is no such method!  That is the cause of the "cannot find symbol error".

There is a constructor `Rectangle(int, int)` but you don't call a constructor in Java.  You `new` it.  For example:

```
  Rectangle someRectangle = new Rectangle(a,b);
```

However, judging from the context, I suspect that you should be assigning the new `Rectangle` objects to elements of the array you created earlier.

But your code is (how shall I say this) "confused".  I think you need to read through it carefully and explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what each statement does.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - kept getting the error - "java: cannot find symbol Rectangle".

In the end, I copied the content of the Rectangle class to notepad, deleted the Rectangle class file and created a new Rectangle class file (all in IntelliJ) and pasted in the old content from notepad.

This worked fine.

Originally, I copied the class file from a previous project, so suspect that is where it was getting confused.

I hope this helps someone else experiencing the same problem.